# SIGHUP is not being sent on exit

Tags: command-line, bash

On ubuntu 14.04.3 (Linux kernel 3.16.53).

UI terminal (created with <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) set with  `shopt -s huponexit` does not generate `SIGHUP` when we type `exit`.

It correctly sends this signal when we click on 'X' to colse the terminal

However it works correctly on tty1.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5458908#post5458908   is being discussed

Answer (score 7):

It is a documented behavior, from `man bash`:

> If the huponexit shell option has been set with shopt, bash sends a
>   SIGHUP to all jobs when an **interactive login** shell exits.

The important words are "interactive" and "login".

When you open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, you are initiating an **interactive**, **non-login** instance of shell, so `huponexit` won't work as expected.

On the other hand, while opening an TTY with e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, you are initiating an **interactive**, **login** session of `bash`, so `huponexit` will work in this case.

On a different note, when you press the `X` button on terminal to close it, the terminal driver in the kernel sends `SIGHUP` to the shell, which in turn sends `SIGHUP` to all its jobs, more technically all of the foreground and background process groups of the session.